# Client SSL certificate for Azure website

Tags: azure, ssl

To start with I have never worked with Azure myself.

I am developing an SSL client application in C which will be accessing over SSL a web site under the `<mywebsite>.azurewebsites.net` domain. The website is secured with the default certificate for the wildcard `*.azurewebsites.net` domain.

My question is what certificate do I need to supply to my client in order to verify the certificate that it will receive from the server? It will have to be the signer's root certificate for the Azure certificate that the server will return, but I am not sure where to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that it has to be the signer's root certificate for the Azure certificate. in that case, the validator companies' root certificate.

Cheking the https properties on *.azurewebsites.net domain names the validator company seems to be Blatimore CyberTrust:

[image: Baltimore CyberTrust]

You could try to download this certificates from different sources:

- [Microsoft itself](https://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps/)
- [ssl-tools website](https://ssl-tools.net/subjects/26102266b387fb8b911bc6d37b35bcd0081c0074)
- [Or also fetch them from several differente certificates storage folders in firefox, chrome, etc.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11850622)

Answer (score 1):

It's this one:

**Baltimore CyberTrust Root**:

[image: Baltimore CyberTrust Root screenshot]

Grab it here:‎
https://baltimore-cybertrust-root.digicert.com/info/index.html

(Thumbprint: `de ‎d4 de 20 d0 5e 66 fc 53 fe 1a 50 88 2c 78 db 28 52 ca e4 74`)